# NextJS: error in getServerSideProps function with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

On the main page (index.js file) I use the getServerSideProps function

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Lang'] = context.locale
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/index?limit=8')
        return {
            props: {
                data: response.data
            },
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            props: {
                error: error
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Everything used to work, but now it's starting to make a mistake

```
connect EADDRNOTAVAIL ip:443 - Local (ip:0)
```

Although if you make a request to the same address in useEffect () - everything works

Tried to upgrade next to version 12 - the error remained

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I think the difference is that you are calling the `useEffect` on the frontend, thus using the host of the frontend, whereas within the `getServerSideProps` function your code is running within a NodeJS server environment and so you need to specify exactly the host instead of `/index`

Comment: the host is substituted correctly

Comment: Is that a screenshot from the browser's console? `getServerSideProps` runs on the server in a Node.js environment, it won't log errors to the browser's console. That error/failed request most likely comes from somewhere else in your client code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const response = await axios.get(`https://yourserver.com/index?limit=8`)
```

and if works replace `https://yourserver.com` by your `.env` variable

Also, try to console.log your variable:

```
const response = await axios.get('/index?limit=8')
console.log(response)
```

And check if your API route has `.get` method

Comment: error as well. I add an additional screen to the text of the question

Comment: I launched the site locally with the same host - and everything works

Comment: The problem is (I think) with absolute paths of your url. Maybe you have CORS enabled

Answer (score 0):

In `getServerSideProps` you have to type the whole url `http://localhost:3000/api/my-end-point`

So I have two instances of axios in nextjs.

```
import Axios from 'axios'

// Use in react component
const ClientAxios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api'
})

// Use in getServerSideProps
const SystemAxios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
})
```